# Image cache url in Magento

Tags: javascript, magento2, magento2.2

I have image url in js variable `/w/s/wsh10-black_main.jpg`.

**Question:** How can I get media cache url in js, like: `https://mydomain.test/media/catalog/product/cache/c687aa7517cf01e65c009f6943c2b1e9/`?

As result I want get full url, like `https://mydomain.test/media/catalog/product/cache/c687aa7517cf01e65c009f6943c2b1e9/w/s/wsh10-black_main.jpg`

Comment: Just concatenate them together.....?

Comment: How can I get media cache url in Magento 2.2.5? Concatenate method I know)))

Answer (score 0):

You need to get base url in order to have the complete url you want. You can do this by defining a function that returns base url so,

```
<?php $baseUrl = $this->getBaseUrl() ; ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getBaseUrl() { return '<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>'; } 
    </script>
```

then use it in JavaScript:

```
var urrl = 'http://'+getBaseUrl()+'/w/s/wsh10-black_main.jpg';
```

You can also refer to this link 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60111/get-base-url-in-js-magento

Hope it helps!

Comment: But in this case urrl = `https://mydomain.test/w/s/wsh10-black_main.jpg`, but I need url with cache code, like this: `https://mydomain.test/media/catalog/product/cache/c687aa7517cf01e65c009f6943c2b1e9/w/s/wsh10-black_main.jpg`

Comment: Okay in that case you will have to add image url.  I think the following link can help you with that 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124371/how-to-get-url-for-static-image-file-in-magento2-javascript-files

Comment: For call getViewFileUrl() I have to put image path. But in my case, I just need path to files (without image). Example: `media/catalog/product/cache/c687aa7517cf01e65c009f6943c2b1e9/`